# How can I mass-update/save all WordPress posts and pages?

Tags: plugins

I'm using a free SEO plugin for WordPress called Rank Math - https://wordpress.org/plugins/seo-by-rank-math/

Overall, I like it a lot. But it has some problems for users with existing WP sites who are importing data from another plugin like Yoast.

Rank Math is relying on individual posts and pages to be edited (not using WP's bulk quick edit feature, but opening each post and re-saving them one-by-one).

This happens with author sitemaps for example. An author's page is only added to the sitemap if I manually open and re-save one of their posts and then re-save the sitemap settings. It doesn't find and add existing authors otherwise.

Is there any way to simulate clicking the "update" button for all posts and pages without changing any actual content in a circumstance like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add to your functions.php file, but dont forget to take it off after use it !!!!!

```
function update_all_posts() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'numberposts' => -1
    );
    $all_posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach ($all_posts as $single_post){
        $single_post->post_title = $single_post->post_title.'';
        wp_update_post( $single_post );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'update_all_posts' );
```

PS : BE SURE TO MAKE A DATABASE BACKUP BEFORE EXECUTE !!!

Comment: Thanks. But as I mentioned in my question, the built-in bulk quick edit feature in WordPress does not work for this. It doesn't trigger any of the necessary actions from the plugin, like the rank calculation. It has to be triggered by the update button on every individual post and page.

Comment: sorry, didn't read enough ;) i've updated my answear with a function to load ! ( load one time, and then take of ;-) )

Comment: Well, partial success! It did pull most of the authors into the author sitemap. For some reason it missed 5, but I'll manually catch those. It did not, unfortunately, trigger the score calculation for each post.

Comment: I think the missing 5 had to do with it being 1500 posts. It was loading for a while then crashed. I'll have to run something again for the score calculations, so for future reference, is there a way something like this could be run in batches so it doesn't cause that crash?

Comment: for this, you should have a look around of php_max_execution_time ! (or run it localy ).

Comment: dont hesitate to validate my answear if it fits to your need !

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to do that, but I'll look into the php_max_execution_time for when I try again for the main problem of the SEO scores. Unfortunately this didn't seem to do anything for that. I put an update in the original question about why that may not have been triggered with your answer. Should I break that into a separate question and then validate this answer because it did technically update the posts?

Comment: i don't know :D on my side, it works ! activate WP_DEBUG to see what error does PHP provide.

Comment: I think I'll do that and split it off since it seems to be a related, but separate issue affecting the rank calculations. I increased the time limit in my wp-config.php and ran the script again just to see if it crashed again, and it seemed to process ok this time. If anyone else has a similar number of posts (1500 or so), set_time_limit(720); did the trick in my case.

Comment: what you can also do, is do it with limit like, 500 posts, then, posts from 501 to 1000, & 1001 to 1500.

Comment: Hmm... didn't work for me. Ran into a few wordpress warnings and that's about it. No updates.

Comment: what are the warnings ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a **smaller server** (such as Shared Hosting), you can use this **WP-CLI** command to update all the posts one at a time. That way, it handles memory without causing a "**503 server error**" and the like.

Create a new file in your theme such as `/wp-content/themes/mytheme/commands.php`:

```php
// add this to your /wp-content/themes/mytheme/commands.php file

if ( ! class_exists( '\WP_CLI' ) ) {
    return;
}

class Update_All_Posts_Command {

    public function __invoke( $args, $assoc_args ) {
        $all_posts = get_posts( array(
            'post_type'    => 'post',
            'numberposts'  => -1,
        ) );

        foreach ( $all_posts as $single_post ) {
            $single_post->post_title = $single_post->post_title . '';
            wp_update_post( $single_post );
            WP_CLI::success( 'Post updated successfully! ID: ' . $single_post->ID );
        }

        WP_CLI::success( 'All posts updated successfully!' );
    }
}

\WP_CLI::add_command( 'update-all-posts', 'Update_All_Posts_Command' );
```

The code above is an enhancement from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/330751/153518) which addresses the memory issue.

Finally, add this to your `functions.php` file:

```php
require_once get_template_directory() . '/commands.php';
```

You can now visit your server's terminal and run the command:

```shell
wp update-all-posts
```

And you will get an output such as this:

[image]